# What would be a good separator look like for a file containing multiple MP4 files?

Tags: python, file, file-type

I am currently trying to make my own file format by simply merging the binary data from multiple video files (.mp4, AVC, AAC to be exact) and separating this data with a separator that my Python script can look for. To split the files after merging them, I am currently using this approach but I believe it has the following problem:

```py
PADDING = bytearray(1024)
def split_file(filepath, index):
    internal_index = 0
    with open(filepath, "rb") as stream:
        buffer = bytes()
        while True:
            chunk = stream.read(10_000_000)
            if not chunk:
                if internal_index == index:
                    yield buffer
                break
            buffer += chunk
            while True:
                try:
                    part, buffer = buffer.split(PADDING, 1)
                except ValueError:
                    break
                else:
                    if internal_index == index:
                        yield part
                    internal_index += 1
```

The separator could be encountered partly at the end of a chunk and would not be detected by the .split method, allowing parts of the separator data to be written into the data that gets poured into the unpacked video files. I tried to check if the end of the chunk contained any \x00 bytes, but if it were the case that the file's data itself had contained this \x00 and it had ended up at the end of the chunk, that'd mean the parser would incorrectly assume this was part of the separator block and would get rid of it.

I also considered making it so that separate files begin at multiples of an offset from the begging of a file, but considering the possible size variation in video files, this approach wouldn't work since I would either have to pad extremely small files for GBs or incorrectly split bigger files into small ones.

So I am trying to look for a way to implement a separator block in between these binary streams so that it is distinguishable from file data and is not prone to failure if it doesn't get read in its entirety. What would be a good way to do so? Thanks.

Comment: You might consider a header to the file that contains pointers to the byte offset into the binary data part of the file...

Comment: Unless each constituent file type provides its own way of determining its own size and format, providing your own header is probably the *only* solution.

Comment: And make sure your header contains a type and version identifier: if you ever decide to change your format, you'll want some way of identifying which version of your format it conforms to.

Comment: ...but also think about why you're creating a new file format, and consider just using something like `tar`, and use your energy for implementing things that are new and exciting. Because there are already so many file formats...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This endeavour is faced with fundamental constraints on how information can be encoded and communicated, which are studied formally in the domains of information theory and communication theory.

Intuitively, suppose we have two chunks of information we want to represent, one after the other.

One possibility is to encode it as <chunk 1> <-separator-> <chunk 2>.  This only works if <chunk 1> and <chunk 2> do not contain <-separator->.  If the chunks are arbitrary binary files it is not safe to assume they will not contain a sequence that matches <-separator->.  Even if you have control over how the chunks are represented you may not want to preclude certain sequences from occurring within a chunk because this will be inefficient--chunks will require more space on average.

The only other possibility is to have advance knowledge of where <chunk 1> ends and <chunk 2> begins.  This is where header information comes in.  You could provide a header on each chunk that said how long that chunk is going to be.  Another option would be to have a single header before the first chunk that said how long each chunk will be.